# How to compute F-measure and accuracy for repeated cross-validation

Tags: classification, cross-validation, bias, accuracy

I am working on bug classification using classifiers but facing some confusion regarding methods to compute measures that capture the predictive power of classifiers. I am running repeated cross-validation, i.e., N x K-CV.
(In each of the N runs, the dataset is randomly distributed in the K bins.)

When N=1, the paper

Forman, George, and Martin Scholz. "Apples-to-apples in cross-validation studies: pitfalls in classifier performance measurement." ACM SIGKDD Explorations Newsletter 12.1 (2010): 49-57.

recommends, that we sum true positives (TP), false positive (FP) and false negatives (FP) over the folds and compute **F-measure** on these aggregates (see pp. 51 in above paper). For **accuracy**, it recommends that one should compute accuracy in each fold, sum them and finally divide the sum by K to get overall accuracy (pp. 52).

My query is, how do I calculate the overall F-measure and accuracy for N x K-CV?

1. F-measure: Should I sum the quantities (i.e., TP, FP, FN) over the N x K runs and compute F-measure using these sums?
2. For accuracy, should we sum the accuracy for each of the N x K runs and simply take their average for the overall estimate?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. F-measure: Should I sum the quantities (i.e., TP, FP, FN) over the N x K runs and compute F-measure using these sums?

Yes! Calculate one f1 for each run of cross-validation and average over the `N` runs. This is also a great opportunity to see the difference between this approach and calculating f1 for each fold and averaging over different folds differ from each other.

2. For accuracy, should we sum the accuracy for each of the N x K runs and simply take their average for the overall estimate?

Also Yes! Good approach. In applications, it is sometimes not about being 100% correct but applying methods and techniques according to their ease of use.

However, whenever you are reporting the mean, please also report the variance or the standard deviation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! For query (1), somehow I feel the quantities (e.g. TP, FP, FN) are added up in case of K-CV since the test sets are always disjoint. So basically, the quantities being added are computed over non-overlapping TP and TN sets. This will be violated whenever I add them across N x K runs. Just wondering if that does not cause an issue.

Comment: In repeated cross-validation scenario, you could calculate one f1 for each run of k-fold cross-validation. I reread my answer and this wasn't clear. I have updated it.